# Replace .equals() with Objects.equals()

Tags: java

I was writing code, when IntelliJ suggested me a correction on:

```
objectOne.equals(objectTwo);
```

telling me that the Method invocation `equals` may produce the good old `java.lang.NullPointerException` , proposing as solution something that I wasn't aware of, [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

```
Objects.equals(objectOne, objectTwo);
```

Reading the documentation I see only one potential problem, which is that if `objectOne == null` and `objectTwo == null` , then the result is `true`.

**At this point the question is:** could I start replacing and using everywhere this method instead of `.equals` ?
Is this a safe approach or I'm missing some big contraindication?

Getting rid of NPE is very attractive...
Thanks

Comment: Why is null == null being true a problem?

Comment: @dustytrash I think this can produce an unwanted behaviour which is hard to find: if I have 2 nulls I will fast notice with `.equals` cause of NPE , but with `Objects.equals` the code will pass through that as a `true` result... it smells like potential hidden bug

Comment: @dustytrash Principle of Least Astonishment. Many languages treat null as not equal to anything

Comment: If you manage to do operations on such objects it's not (obviously) recommend to use this method cause you can't know which is null. It just check if two objects are equals

Comment: *could I start replacing and using everywhere this method instead of .equals*: no. A null variable should be the exception. If a variable can be null, then using Objects.equals() is an option. Otherwise,if a variable is not supposed to be null, and you get an NPE, that means the code has a bug, and the bug should be fixed.

Comment: what is the need of checking if two objects are null?

Comment: If you can't assert that `objectOne` isn't `null`, then in the case when it is, you would have that `NullPointerException`

Comment: If an object is null, surly it would produce an NPE somewhere right? I don't believe anyone should use `.equals()` as a way of producing an unhandled NPE so that they can "easily see and debug the 'issue'". Instead you should check if the object is null.

Comment: The correct way to handle this situation depends entirely on the context of this comparison. How are `objectOne` and `objectTwo` being used after this line of code? Please edit your question to show a complete method to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you helped me clearing my mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is NO bulletproof answer for this question, as it depends on the needs of the program and how it should answer to that exceptional scenario. Saying that, I would say:

If having a null is a **programmer's error** (I mean something that you will never expect to happen inside your algorithms) I would suggest to leave the `.equals` method as a null pointer exception will arise and make you take notice of the problem, I mean, a programmer's error (Those errors that we don't want!, that means that we wrote bad an algorithm), and you should thanks the application for reporting it (instead of an angry real client....)

But if in the other hand your application could work as well, not considering that as a programmer error, then using `Object.equals` will fit better to your needs.

The general wisdom suggest that exceptions should at least be logged.

### Summary

Try to investigate about different kinds of exceptions. Not all the exceptions are programmer errors.

In Java, usually, the **checked exceptions** are for all those events that you can anticipate, you can write code that should be able to handle. And the **unchecked Exceptions** (those that belongs the RuntimeException's family) are for events that you just can not anticipate (like null pointer exceptions), thus it is impossible to write code to handle things that you don't expect (instead you should correct the already existing code, not writing new code!).

Comment: i try to say a bullet proff answer, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Did you mean bulletproof?

Comment: right! please be my guess and edit my answer, i'm not (ENGLISH) native speaker. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Victor Already fixed. Needed a little more context to understand what you meant.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added more context, hope it is more clear now. And thanks again

Comment: This is probably what I was looking for... It's better to not using that as default, but adapting that on the situation. Thanks

Comment: I meant in the first sentence. An early edit was enough to understand what you were trying to say with the word "proff".

Comment: @Leviand this happens quite often when soemone try to do good code!. It is not easy, but let's says that somethings are expected to happens and some not. Only the author of the program know that. For example, what happens if your program your out of memory? or if you have a network failaure? or a disk access error beacuse another process is using the file? those are exceptional scenarios that doesn't imply the existance of a programmer error. I added aditional context in order to boost a little the learning curve!

Answer (score 7):

It is an appropriate approach if you want to allow null values. Otherwise you could just add a check for null values and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your code and what 'everywhere' means. If your code currently assumes (maybe not explicitly but just by the fact that null input will never propagate beyond the `equals` call ) that null input will result in an NPE, then switching to `Objects.equals` will introduce a bug.